# Runtime analysis

Tags: c, data-structures, runtime

```
int i, j;

for(i=0; i<n*n; i++) 
{
    if(i % n == 0)
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
             x++;
    else 
        x--;
}
```

I'm new to runtime analysis so I'm just checking my answer on here to see if I have the right idea.

I have to find a tight runtime bound for that segment and give a reasoning.

I came up with O(n²).

My reasoning behind it is because it runs the first for loop n² times. It only runs the second for loop if i is divisible by n.

Is this okay or am I completely wrong in my analysis?

Comment: It runs the first loop n^2 times, not 2n times!

Comment: My math skills :(. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer loop runs `n²` times. Every `n`-th run (so n runs in total), it starts another loop, which runs `n` times. That amounts to `n² + n * n` which equals `2n²` which is a runtime of O(n²).