# Time Complexity of Nested for Loops with if Statements

Tags: c++, c, big-o

How does the if-statement of this code affect the time complexity of this code?

Based off of this question: [Runtime analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656270/runtime-analysis), the for loop in the if statement would run n*n times. But in this code, *j* outpaces *i* so that once the second loop is run `j = i^2`. What does this make the time complexity of the third for loop then? I understand that the first for loop runs n times, the second runs `n^2` times, and the third runs `n^2` times for a certain amount of times when triggered. So the complexity would be given by `n*n^2(xn^2)` for which `n` is the number of times the if statement is true. The complexity is not simply `O(n^6)` because the if-statement is not true n times right?

```
int n;
int sum;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < i*i; j++)
    {
      if (j % i == 0)
        {
          for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
              sum++;
            }           
        }       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `if` condition will be true when `j` is a multiple of `i`; this happens `i` times as `j` goes from 0 to `i * i`, so the third `for` loop runs only `i` times. The overall complexity is O(n^4).

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < i*i; j++)       // Runs O(n) times
    {
      if (j % i == 0)                 // Runs O(n) × O(n^2) = O(n^3) times
        {
          for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) // Runs O(n) × O(n) = O(n^2) times
            {
              sum++;                  // Runs O(n^2) × O(n^2) = O(n^4) times
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *this happens `i` times as j goes from `0` to `i * i`, so the third for loop runs only `i` times.* does not sound right. Shouldn't it be `i*i - i` times?

Comment: @RSahu You're reading it backwards. The `k` loop runs when `j` is a multiple of `i`.

Comment: @RSahu: How many multiples of 9 are there from 0 to 9² - 1 = 80? Let's count them: 0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72: total 9.

Comment: @AlexP, I see your logic. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AlexP could you please explain why the time complexity is O(n^4) instead of O(n^5). The third loop is dependent on the second inner loop and second inner loop has O(n^2) time complexity. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Ashwathama: The second loop runs O(n^2) times for each iteration of the outer loop, yes. But the **if** condition which governs the third loop if **true** only O(n) times for each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 3):

> The complexity is not simply O(n^6) because the if-statement is not true n times right?

No, it is not.

At worst, it is going to be `O(n^5)`. It is less than that since `j % i` is equal to `0` only `i` times.

The first loop is run `n` times.
The second loop is run `O(n^2)` times.
The third loop is run at most `O(n)` times.

The worst combined complexity of the loop is going to be `O(n) x O(n^2) x O(n)`, which is `O(n^4)`.

Comment: The third loop is run O(n) times each time the second loop runs, because there are only *i* multiples of *i* from 0 to *i²*. Since the second loop is entered O(n) times, the third loop is entered O(n^2) times.